# UITableView doesn't display based on its height in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have an expandable UITableView, which can expand/collapse when users press a button.
The way is that I change its content when the button is pressed, and assign the contentSize.height to the height of the tableview. It works properly in iOS 6.

However, in iOS 7, no matter what value I set to the height of the tableview, it displays like the height is never changed and the new content is cut off. The height seems to stick to the origin height in the storyboard. But if I print the height of the tableview, it's right the value I set.

Here is how I change its height:

```
//Do some change to the content...
[tableview reloadData];
NSLog(@"height: %f, contentHeight: %f", tableview.frame.size.height, tableview.contentSize.height);// print height: 60, contentHeight: 160
CGRect frame = tableview.frame;
frame.size.height = tableview.contentSize.height;
tableview.frame = frame;
NSLog(@"height: %f, contentHeight: %f", tableview.frame.size.height, tableview.contentSize.height);// print height: 160, contentHeight: 160
```

Any ideas?

p.s. The tableview is in a UIScrollView. (if it matters.)

Comment: Every `UITableView` is in a `UIScrollView` by default. If you've added another one manually, you really shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Why are you putting your UITableView in another UIScrolView ? Do you really need it ? In fact, like Marko said, the UITableView already herits from UIScrollView so maybe removing your scrollview container will responds to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the scrollview.
try something like this:

```
CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(screen.size.width, screen.size.height);
[self.scrollView addSubview:tableview];
scrollViewContentSize.height += tableview.frame.size.height;
[self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```